# Exibir código jquery em um ID

Tags: html, jquery

Galeria preciso de ajuda com meu código, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
onFinish: function () { <br><br> 
    console.log('registrationStoreId') 
    console.log(pmMVCHelpers.user.getProperty('registrationStoreId'));

    var registrationStoreId = $("#loja").text(


     if($('registrationStoreId').val() = "17"){
        .text(NA LOJA UM EM ATÉ <br> 05 DIAS ÚTEIS)

    } 

     else if ($('registrationStoreId').val() = "34"){
        .text(NA LOJA DOIS EM ATÉ <br> 05 DIAS ÚTEIS)

    }

    else ($('registrationStoreId').val() = " "){
        .text(EM ATÉ 15 DIAS ÚTEIS)
    } 
};
```

Comment: O que da errado? Recebe algum erro?

Comment: Não coloque o `if` dentro do método `.text`.

Comment: Vc está querendo enviar um texto para a `div` dependendo do `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para adicionar um código no formato de texto dentro de um elemento, é necessário converter-lo para *String* ou usar [*Template String*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

Para utilizar o *Template String*, basta envolver o código com o acento grave `` ` ``, por exemplo:

```js
$("#codigo").text(`if ($('registrationStoreId').val() = "17") {
    .text(NA LOJA UM EM ATÉ < br > 05 DIAS ÚTEIS)

  } else if ($('registrationStoreId').val() = "34") {
    .text(NA LOJA DOIS EM ATÉ < br > 05 DIAS ÚTEIS)

  } else($('registrationStoreId').val() = " ") {
    .text(EM ATÉ 15 DIAS ÚTEIS)
  }
}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre><code id="codigo"></code></pre>
```